# Module front controllers 404 Prestashop 1.7.8

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on a custom payment plugin in Prestashop 1.7. I created a callback URL

But the page returned 404 **"The page you are looking for was not found.
"**. This is a controller path:

/controllers/front/Validation.php

```
$callback_url = $this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'Validation', [], true);
$this->context->smarty->assign([
        'callback_url' => $callback_url)];
```

What's wrong!

Thank you for your support

Comment: please share your module controller class

Answer (score 0):

You should to reset the module after you have created the Validation.php file.
Have you tried to reset the module?

Comment: Yes. I reset the module. But still has the same problem.